# Using AJAX HTML JSON and JSP for refreshing a displayed Datatable clarification

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

Hello I'm currently in the process of having a table that shows rows and columns pertaining to States and Products respectively.  My issue is I am looking for a way to refresh the datatable with new elements whenever new data is input, as well as having those updated values have a change in color.  I am fairly new to AJAX and had a few questions that I cant seem to find after searching the web for a day now

The following is returning the values is being printed out in the console, but I cannot figure a way to print them out through html because each of the products have unique values for each state.  I was hoping to take these parsedJson values and have them visible in a string or some form to cross reference them to old values and update them (perhaps a hashmap) and then print the values from the hashmap afterwards.

```
function updateTable(name){
    console.log(name);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "SalesProductsAjax.jsp" ,
        data: "name=" + name,
        beforeSend:function(){
            //Update Stats
            console.log('Request Sent');
        },
        success:function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            var i = Object.keys(response).length-1;
            console.log(i);
            while ( i >= 0 ){
                var keyStr = Object.keys(response)[i];
                console.log("#" + name + " ." + keyStr + "$" + response[keyStr]);
                $("#" + name + " ." + keyStr).html("$" + response[keyStr]);
                i--;
            }
            //console.log(Object.keys(response)[0]);
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error:function(){
            // Failed request
            console.log("FAIL");
        }
    });
}   
productsR.beforeFirst(); 
while (productsR.next()){
    %>updateTable("<%=productsR.getString("name")%>");<%
}%>
function getChanges(){
    <% 
    productsR.beforeFirst(); 
    while (productsR.next()){
        %>updateTable("<%=productsR.getString("name")%>");  
    }%>
```

I have some JSP code in between that calls queries for the rows and columns and prints them out in html with the getString() function, but I was wondering if there was a way to save the JSON parsed object so I could somehow put them in the hashmap as well and compare values in order to get the results I needed!

Comment: You are mixing client script with server script, kindly avoid that. I see you have used some jdbc jsp scriplets with js. You will end up with un-expected results.

Comment: With regards to that, how would one utilize either server or client side programming to be able to compare old with new updated data and indicate it through html when refreshed?  Should it be done through js or jsp?

Comment: Push all your client scripts to external js, you will end up with jsp with html and server scripts. Also use of scriplets are not recommended, use jstl instead.